# Inverted pair of complex analytic families

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, open-problems

I read the following "problem" in an old set of notes of Morrow and Kodaira which focused on deformations of complex manifolds:

*Find a pair of complex analytic families $\lbrace M_t\rbrace$ and $\lbrace N_t\rbrace$ with $|t|<1$ such that $M_t=N_0$ for $t\ne 0$ and $N_t=M_0$ for $t\ne0$, with $M_0\ne N_0$.* (Every manifold assumed compact.)

As of 1971 there were no known examples. **Up to date, is this possibly true?**

Naively it seems impossible. In the spirit of Lefschetz fibrations, we have $M_0$ as a critical level set amongst the $M_t$ (thinking of cylinders which get pinched via a vanishing cycle). It is then not generic, and any perturbation of this fiber (locally about the nodal point) would alter the topology. So to me the inverted family $\lbrace N_t\rbrace$ couldn't exist, because it would force a generic $M_{t_0}$ to take over the role as the critical level set amongst the $N_t$, but there is nothing "non-regular" about it.
If the manifolds are allowed to be noncompact, perhaps it's easy, again via a rough sketch: take $\lbrace M_t\rbrace$ to be the family of open cylinders which pinch the vanishing cycles at $t=0$, and $\lbrace N_t\rbrace$ to be the family of "pinched" cylinders where the pinching point pushes off to infinity as $|t|\to 0$.

**Edit:** The problem is more subtle than I thought, and my example with Lefschetz fibrations doesn't apply. From the definition of a "complex analytic family", all $M_t$ are diffeomorphic to each other (in particular, they're all nonsingular spaces), and so we can only distinguish them by their holomorphic structures. In other words, $M_0\ne N_0$ means diffeomorphic but not complex-analytically homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your objects are compact analytic spaces and show that then the situation you describe cannot arise. I don't have access to Morrow and Kodaira and cannot remember whether the "problem" concerns only compact manifolds.

Suppose that $\mathcal M\to S$ is a miniversal deformation of $M_0$. Then the given family $\{M_t\}$ defines a morphism $\mu:\Delta\to S$, where $\Delta$ is a complex disc. Since $M_t=N_0\ne M_0$, the map $\mu$ is non-constant and $\mu(\Delta-\{0\})$ is contained in the stratum of $S$ that consists of points $s$ such that $\mathcal M_s$ is isomorphic to $N_0$. Now this stratum is smooth and its dimension, which we have just proved to be at least $1$, equals $\dim Aut_{M_0}-\dim Aut_{N_0}$; one reference for this, in the algebraic context (but in the current analytic context the result will be the same), is Theorem 2.7 of arXiv:1210.0342 by Hyland, Ekedahl and Shepherd-Barron. (In positive or mixed characteristic, where group schemes need not be reduced, this dimension becomes $\dim Lie(Aut_{M_0})-\dim Aut_{N_0}$.)

So $\dim Aut_{N_0}<\dim Aut_{M_0}$. From the assumptions, the opposite inequality is also valid, and we have a contradiction.